# Why did my <h1> disappear?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I was editing my styles.css on a WordPress site to remove the title on a particular page. To do this I used the following code:

```
.post-name .entry-title { display: none; }
```

This removed the title like I expected. I then enter the following code to remove a border that was after the header:

```
.post-name .entry-header::after { border-bottom: none; }
```

This bit of code didn't work. I then removed both pieces of code that I added to try and start from scratch. Now when I view the page, my title is still missing, but the bottom border stayed. I tried clearing my browser's cached images and files, but that didn't work.

What could have caused the title to be permanently missing and why didn't the second bit of code work (I also check my specificity and the above ::after code took priority)?

Thank you!

Comment: What shows up in your developer tools when you press F12? Is the H1 in the DOM? Is there CSS being applied still?

Comment: Your second code won't work unless you added the border the same way

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   In this case however, I'd suggest providing a link to the relevant site.

Answer (score 0):

that is odd.

try making it re-appear by

```
.post-name .entry-title { display: block; }
```